# What would you name this object?

Tags: naming-conventions

So I have a table like so:

```
   =========================
   ID | Col2 | col3 | col4 |
   =========================
-> 21 | balh | blah |  foo |
   22 | balh | blah |  foo |
```

I am making a object that can read the data from one row using the column name in an expression. Something like this:

```
 myrow.getValue(col => col.Col2)
```

The problem I am having is at the moment is naming the object, I can't really find a name that describes what it does without being really long.

What would you call it?

**EDIT** Ok I'll add a few more details, I am working with a COM object which will only let me read one column at a time.  So I am writing a wrapper which can fetch a row from a table(inside the COM object) using the ID, then let the user supply a column name using expression(details not important).  The object goes off to the table and get the data  for that row using the ID and column name.

Comment: @sara provide a better solution and I would be happy to change :)

Comment: So the wrapper represents a Row, and then you have methods which let you request a column at a time.  So call it Row?  RowProxy?  Datarow?

Comment: @Chris B Thats is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Check last updates + comments of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

RowReader?

Code would look like (some variations of the Get naming)

```
var reader = new RowReader(sourceRow);

//var value = reader.GetValue(col => col.Col2);
//var value = reader.ByColumn(col => col.Col2);
//var value = reader.ReadColumn (col => col.Col2);
```

Based on info by others, perhaps: RowColumnsReader. In which case the method would be Read.

Comment: My first suggestion as well.  But thinking about it, it doesn't tell you whether you're reading Rows by asking about Columns, or reading Columns by asking about Rows.  Deeply ambiguous. (See "ColumnReader")

Comment: Added sample code, with some variations of the Get/Read, specially the latter 2 make it explicit that it is a column.

Comment: Anything containing 'Read' or 'Write' in a function name will suggest a streaming operation.

Comment: Likewise, having Reader in the class name suggests a Stream.

Comment: well, call it coincidence, but check the Nathan's update ... I would say it plays well with that :)

Answer (score 1):

I would take this one step back and ask: **Why are you creating a new object specifically for reading values from a column?**

It sounds to me that it would be better to create a new *method* (e.g. readColumn()) in the class which is encapsulating the table itself.

**This would be better OO practice.**

A class models an object which has:

- Certain attributes/data (member *data*)
- Certain behaviour (member *methods*).

In your particular case, the table is the *data*, and reading is the *behaviour* that is performed on that *data*.

For this reason, a read method should be implemented as a method in the existing data class.

If you create another class to read the data, you will probably need to open up the class which is storing the data (e.g. by using friend classes in C++).  This violates the encapsulation of the class, as you are suddenly allowing outside classes free access to your data, albeit in a potentially controlled fashion.

Comment: @Leo...: Yours belongs to the "comments" rather than "answers"  no downvoting anyway.

Comment: @Oscar - Why does it belong in the comments?  Isn't it valid to give an answer proposing an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

ColumnSpaceShipRowReader

If you are storing space ships.

Answer (score 1):

Bob? :-)

If you creating a method for getting some data from a row using a column name, then the thing you want is a method not an object?

```
data = row.read(columnName);
```

matches your description. If you're more specific than that, you can use that names that closer reflect your actual domain or level of abstraction.

In general, if you can describe what you are doing in a sentence or two, the nouns are objects and the verbs are methods.

Answer (score 1):

That's a method of an object rather than an object itself, but my personal choice would be `myRow.ReadRowByCol(...)` since that captures the intent. But I like Paul's "Bob" as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnReader`?

Answer (score 0):

How is this different from doing:

```
myrow.Select(col => col.Col2);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

ColumnDataFetcher

**EDITED**

after: abatishchev comments. Thank you abatishchev.

Answer (score 0):

RowRenderer

Answer (score 0):

`RowReader`?  `RowByColumn`?  `ColumnGrabber`?

Really, the issue is that you should be designing the `Row` object--an object that encapsulates the data associated with a given row (the `ID`, I guess in your case) and the methods *on* that object should be returning the values.  Call the `Row` object the "`Row`" or "`Case`" or "`DataReference`" or whatever makes sense for your application.  Then the methods are easy to name (e.g., `Row.getColumn('col2')`)

**Note**: `RowReader`, on reflection, is a terrible name for this class.  It's ambiguous, because it's reading *columns*, not rows.  `ColumnReader` is also bad, for the opposite reason (it reads columns by reading a row).  The `Row` needs the class, not the function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're describing a method, not an object.

If your object is to represent the value of a column at a certain row, then I guess it'd be pretty save to call it a Cell.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer `valueAt` over `getValue`:

```
myrow. valueAt( col => col.Col2 );
```

Also, it could be nice and meaningful to have the `[]` operator overloaded:

```
var x = myRow["name"];
var x = myRow[ col => col.Col2 ];
```